# Kofax Total Agility-Web Service Call

Tags: kofax

I am currently working on building a workflow within Kofax Total Agility Process Designer. Upon analysis, understood that KTA would be able to call an external webservice.

I wanted to know if there is anyway we could send across byte[] through the webservice call from within KTA designer.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although much of the KTA API can be called from the interface within the KTA Designer, some functions would need to be called from code (script activity or .NET assembly).  Functions that use a byte array as inputs or output are a good example of functions that would need to be called in code, because the variables in the designer don't have a way to represent a byte array.

Comment: Hi Stephen, Thanks a lot for your reply. I also had the same line of thought to have a .Net node generate the bytes for a given document id. Do you mind sharing any additional information or an example where i could get an idea of how to generate the bytes. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: From a general .NET perspective, if you are trying to pass a file as a byte array, I would think that using File.ReadAllBytes would be the simplest approach: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readallbytes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Hi Stephen , thanks a lot for your reply.So from my understanding the c# node would be able to generate the byte[].But once the byte array is generated, how do we send those bytes via a webservice call.If you could share your thoughts on that it would be really helpful.

Comment: When you are already inside of a KTA process you would not call the API through the web service, you would simply add a reference to the SDK dll.  You will want to go to the API documentation and read the topics under the Examples section for details on how to creating a dll with the proper references.  (I strongly recommend a building a dll over a script activity.)  You would only call the API via web services if you were using code completely external to KTA and calling something from the outside.